# LINQ Grouping: Is there a cleaner way to do this without a for loop

Tags: linq

I am trying to create a very simple distribution chart and I want to display the counts of tests score percentages in their corresponding 10's ranges.

I thought about just doing the grouping on the Math.Round((d.Percentage/10-0.5),0)*10 which should give me the 10's value....but I wasn't sure the best way to do this given that I would probably have missing ranges and all ranges need to appear even if the count is zero. I also thought about doing an outer join on the ranges array but since I'm fairly new to Linq so for the sake of time I opted for the code below. I would however like to know what a better way might be.

Also note: As I tend to work with larger teams with varying experience levels, I'm not all that crazy about ultra compact code unless it remains very readable to the average developer.

Any suggestions?

```
public IEnumerable<TestDistribution> GetDistribution()
    {
        var distribution = new List<TestDistribution>();
        var ranges = new int[] { 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110 };
        var labels = new string[] { "0%'s", "10%'s", "20%'s", "30%'s", "40%'s", "50%'s", "60%'s", "70%'s", "80%'s", "90%'s", "100%'s", ">110% "};

        for (var n = 0; n < ranges.Count(); n++)
        {
            var count = 0;
            var min = ranges[n];
            var max = (n == ranges.Count() - 1) ? decimal.MaxValue : ranges[n+1];

            count = (from d in Results
                     where d.Percentage>= min 
                     && d.Percentage<max
                     select d)
                     .Count();

            distribution.Add(new TestDistribution() { Label = labels[n], Frequency = count });
        }

        return distribution;
    }
```

Comment: A slight curve ball. After some testing I've adjusted the ranges to be <25, 25-50, 50-60, 60-70, 70-85, 85-100 (represents Letter grades) and will map to "U","F","D","C","B","A". These ranges will be dynamically set and not hard coded, so there's no way to put a simple incrementor to define the grouping.

Comment: A class/struct for ranges will help, with Min, Max and Label properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
// ranges and labels in a list of pairs of them

var rangesWithLabels = ranges.Zip(labels, (r,l) => new {Range = r, Label = l});

// create a list of intervals (ie. 0-10, 10-20, .. 110 - max value
var rangeMinMax = ranges.Zip(ranges.Skip(1), (min, max) => new {Min = min, Max = max})
                        .Union(new[] {new {Min = ranges.Last(), Max = Int32.MaxValue}});

//the grouping is made by the lower bound of the interval found for some Percentage     
var resultsDistribution = from c in Results                               
             group c by 
                 rangeMinMax.FirstOrDefault(r=> r.Min <= c.Percentage && c.Percentage < r.Max).Min into g
            select new {Percentage = g.Key, Frequency = g.Count() };                            
// left join betweem the labels and the results with frequencies      
var distributionWithLabels = 
        from l in rangesWithLabels
        join r in resultsDistribution on l.Range equals r.Percentage 
               into rd
               from r in rd.DefaultIfEmpty()                
        select new TestDistribution{
            Label = l.Label,
            Frequency = r != null ? r.Frequency : 0
        };
distribution = distributionWithLabels.ToList();
```

Another solution if the ranges and labels can be created in another way

```
var ranges = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                .Select(c=> new {
                       Min = c * 10, 
                       Max = (c +1 )* 10, 
                       Label = (c * 10) + "%'s"})
                .Union(new[] { new {
                          Min = 100, 
                      Max = Int32.MaxValue,
                      Label =  ">110% "
                }});
var resultsDistribution = from c in Results                               
                          group c by ranges.FirstOrDefault(r=> r.Min <= c.Percentage && c.Percentage < r.Max).Min  
                                     into g
                          select new {Percentage = g.Key, Frequency = g.Count() };

var distributionWithLabels = 
        from l in ranges
        join r in resultsDistribution on l.Min equals r.Percentage 
               into rd
               from r in rd.DefaultIfEmpty()                
        select new TestDistribution{
            Label = l.Label,
            Frequency = r != null ? r.Frequency : 0
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
public IEnumerable<TestDistribution> GetDistribution()
{
    var range = 12;

    return Enumerable.Range(0, range).Select(
        n => new TestDistribution
                {
                    Label = string.Format("{1}{0}%'s", n*10, n==range-1 ? ">" : ""),
                    Frequency =
                        Results.Count(
                            d =>
                            d.Percentage >= n*10
                            && d.Percentage < ((n == range - 1) ? decimal.MaxValue : (n+1)*10))
                });
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but I like it. I suppose I could create a simple array of ranges and then do a select on it like you have done above. Good idea :)